# ASP.NET Core Application Insights adaptive sampling

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

TL;DR: Does ExcludedTypes in Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore SDK default to Exception and Trace?

I am running an ASP.NET Core 2.2 app with version 2.6.1 Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore SDK. I am reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#configuring-adaptive-sampling-for-aspnet-applications where they write that the default values for ExcludedTypes is Trace and Exception, which is just the way i like it, but I am wondering, since the default values is for ASP.NET (actually specified in the application insights config for the host), if these default values also apply for ASP.NET Core applications that doesnt have an application insights config file (all config is done through code).

I know that the SDK is open sourced, but I haven't been able to search through it and find the initial values: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore. Maybe I am just searching for the wrong things.

Comment: Please refer to the updated answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Yes, the default ExcludedTypes for asp.net core is Event. There'are 2 places mentionded that:

1.In this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#frequently-asked-questions), it says "In ASP.NET Core, exact same default behavior is enabled in code.":

[image]

2.In the source code, you can find it's defined [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/Implementation/TelemetryConfigurationOptionsSetup.cs#L178):

[image]

---

First, the default values for ExcludedTypes is not Trace and Exception, it is Event. There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/32629) for that. And I also tested it myself, the default ExcludedType is Event indeed.

For asp.net core, the default ExcludedType should be same as asp.net, you can take a look at [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#frequently-asked-questions) of the article you provided. I'll try to go through the code to find out what's in the code for asp.net core and will update you later.